# Can't find utf8.js.map pusher-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pusher

this is the error:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/pusher-js/dist/web/pusher.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/cookie/Desktop/cookiecoin/client/node_modules/pusher-js/dist/web/utf8.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cookie/Desktop/cookiecoin/client/node_modules/pusher-js/dist/web/utf8.js.map'
 @ ./src/pages/Coins.jsx 10:0-31 22:21-27
 @ ./src/App.jsx 15:0-34 126:42-47
 @ ./src/index.jsx 6:0-24 8:38-41

1 warning has detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.
```

i tried creating the file and still got the error i also went to the src code of the npm package on github, and it didn't have that file so i'm just a little confused what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug report for this on the pusher-js library. Best to post on that thread for suggestions.
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/issues/535